# How to retrieve an input element and its surrounded span?

Tags: javascript, input, html

For

```
<span id="" ...>
  <input id="" ...>
```

Is there any way to retrieve span id? input element is embedded within span?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("inputId").parentNode;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery:

```
$('#input-id').parent().attr('id');
```

If not:

```
document.getElementById('input-id').parentNode.getAttribute('id');
```

EDIT: Ooops - removed extra parentheses after parentNode!

Answer (score 0):

```
var parentControl = document.getElementByID("id goes here").parentNode;
```